# XTestFakeButtonEvent not working on GNOME bar

Tags: c++, linux, x11

I'm writing an accessibility application that mouse-clicks for the user by using the keyboard. I'm using

```
Display *display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
XTestFakeButtonEvent(display, button, true, CurrentTime); // true is 'mouse down'
XFlush(display);
XCloseDisplay(display);
```

and it works great on any window I can see, except the GNOME upper bar (the upper bar with the date and time and to the right the icons including the "shut down" icon):

[image]

This bar seems to ignore completely the X11 events I'm generating with the code above.

Why is this happening? Any way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that generating a 'button release' event before the two 'button down'+'button release' events fixed it.